# Regular expression pattern for a string like 12,345,678,900?

Tags: javascript, regex

As you can see from the title, I would like to write a regular expression pattern to find a string that consists of various numbers and is separated by comma every three digits. The length of string can vary.

I am still pretty new to regular expression thingy so can anyone help me with that? Thanks a lot in advance.

P.S.
Anyone could also suggest some of good resources, like website, books, etc, for learning regular expression?

Comment: some resources: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for reference is not bad. http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html for testing or maybe http://regexpal.com/

Comment: The MSDN, PHP, Java, and Mozila JavaScript docs all have guides on how to do regex, and for the most part they're not language specific, so you can read any of those.  I personally like the PHP and Mozilla docs...haven't read the MSDN one yet.

Comment: Can you try this regex: `^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$`

Comment: @anubhava That only matches when the entire string is the numeral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex shall match that:

```
\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*
```

If you want to exclude match to a substring of an ill-formed pattern, you might want to do:

```
(?:\A|[^,\d])(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\z|[^,\d])
```

**Explanation of the first regex**

```
\d{1,3}        1 to 3 consecutive numerals
,\d{3}         A comma followed by 3 consecutive numerals
(?:,\d{3})*    Zero or more repetition of a non-capturing group of a comma followed by 3 consecutive numerals
```

**Explanation of the second regex**

```
(?:\A|[^,\d])         A non-capturing group of either the beginning of the string, or anything other than comma or numeral
(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)  A capturing group of 1 to 3 consecutive numerals followed by zero or more repetition of a non-capturing group of a comma followed by 3 consecutive numerals
(?:\z|[^,\d])         A non-capturing group of either the end of the string, or anything other than comma of numeral
```

Comment: It matches 4 digits between comma too

Comment: I tried it in http://regexpal.com/ and it's not matching...is there something wrong with regexpal?

Comment: @sawa if you try test **1,2345,678,900** on this page http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html, it will show 'successful match'

Comment: @woodykiddy I think it should, It should match `1,234`.

Comment: The `^` and `$` markers have to be used `/^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$/` otherwise `1234` matches...

Comment: @sawa could you explain a little bit about the part, **?:** what's that doing actually? Thanks very much.

Comment: @ring0 That will match only when the entire string is the numeral

Comment: @ring0 but it then will not match 1,234,567 :(

Answer (score 0):

Try http://regexlib.com for good examples and links to tools to help you get up to speed with RegEx

Also try this regex tester app http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

And another tool I've used before here http://osherove.com/tools